# How to make HTTP request to custom IP in k6 load testing API?

Tags: k6

Is it possible to force a k6 HTTP request to a custom IP?

i.e. DNS has host name pointing to IP address A, while a test website, same hostname, is on IP address B; need to send k6 load test requests to website B.

It's HTTPS, so there's certificate issues calling https://[ip address] and headers Host: [hostname] (shows "x509: cannot validate certificate for [ip address] because it doesn't contain any IP SANs" messages)

Working from localhost I'm currently editing /etc/hosts as a work around.

Setting IP address is possible in the loadimpact.com API (https://loadimpact.com/load-script-api#http), I'm hoping could be done via k6 API.

Answer (score 2):

No, not yet without running into the SNI issue you describe with TLS. We have an issue to track the DNS override feature here: https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/474

As you mention, modifying the local /etc/hosts or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file is the workaround until this has been implemented in k6.

Comment: Seems to be merged now: https://github.com/grafana/k6/pull/494